# How to determine parasitic capacitance of a diode according to the datasheet?

Tags: diodes, switch-mode-power-supply, capacitance

In order to do simulation, I would like to determine the parasitic diode capacitance of a diode according to this datasheet, when the information is not present into the datasheet... (Simulation model does not always include the parasitic capacitance of the diodes and all diodes are not present or cannot be imported in LTspice (if LTspice is used)

Here is the datasheet of the STTA512B. It is a power diode.

https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/389/CD00004898-49287.pdf

Thank you very much

Comment: I see a capacitance value given on the first page of the datasheet. What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**How to determine parasitic capacitance of a diode according to the datasheet?**"

There are two simple answers.

1) Read the data sheet and take the value you see . In the case of the data sheet you link, it is stated as being 12 pF.

2) Unless the data sheet provides a graph, you can't.

In general, reverse-biased diodes show a capacitance which decreases with applied voltage. Note that the data sheet you linked only specifies 12 pF at 2000 volts. At 200 volts the capacitance will be a good deal greater. This effect is different for different diode impurity profiles. For instance, tuneable RF circuits will often use varicaps, whose construction is chosen specifically to permit large capacitance variations with applied voltage. Another good example is silicon photodiodes, whose capacitance varies with bias voltage. Since such capacitance affects circuit stability in transimpedance amplifiers, photodiode data sheets typically do provide a capacitance vs reverse voltage graph.

Comment: Thank you ! That was completely my bad ! I m sorry ! However your point was good to know !